# Retag? ("braces" and "brackets")

Tags: discussion, tagging

Is there any kind of sensible difference between the tags [braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/braces) and [brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brackets)? If not, probably [brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brackets) should be made a synonym for [braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/braces); if so, the wikis need to explain it better, especially due to the ambiguity/regional variation in the meaning of "brackets": it can refer not only to `{}` and `[]`, but also to `()`, or even `<>`(!) (but hopefully not here, as we have the proper `\langle` and `\rangle` at our disposal). (For U.K. readers: mentally rearrange the appearances of the delimiter pairs above to suit.)

Answer (score 4):

I think [braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/braces) was originally created for things like `\underbrace` or big braces next to text. As such I think we can make it as synonym of [brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brackets), but I would keep the tag about typesetting braces/brackets/parentheses/...

For the TeX source code symbol (that you are describing in your proposed tag wiki edit), maybe we should introduce [grouping](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grouping)? That would cover the catcode 1 and 2 symbols, as well as `\bgroup` etc.

Comment: No, "grouping" wouldn't cover it; the symbols are also used for delimiting arguments and macro bodies (and likely for other things) which do not involve grouping.

Comment: I *do* agree that it is desirable to have distinct tags for the two things, though; I just don't think "grouping" is a good name for the tag about the syntactical braces, and I can't really think of a good new name for either half of the existing tag, except maybe "brace-symbols" for the kind that appear on paper...